# When is the callback MIPInfoCallback called during IloCplex branch & cut?

Tags: callback, cplex, mixed-integer-programming

I am using the IloCplex library in C++ and I am wondering when exactly the callback MIPInfoCallback is called during resolution. In the documentation it only says "IloCplex calls the user-written callback **regularly** during the branch-and-cut search".
Is it called at every node? If so, is it before or after processing the node (i.e. before or after solving the relaxation and adding any cuts)?

Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

CPLEX > User's Manual for CPLEX > Advanced programming techniques  > Using legacy optimization callbacks > Informational callbacks

We can read

What is an informational callback?

Defines an informational callback.

> An informational callback is a user-written routine that enables your
> application to access information about the current mixed integer
> programming (MIP) optimization without sacrificing performance and
> without interfering in the search of the solution space. The
> algorithms call an informational callback when the algorithm finds it
> appropriate; for some algorithms, an informational callback is called
> at every node; for other algorithms, an informational callback is
> called at convenient points in the progress of the algorithm.

Comment: I tested this callback on different examples and the moment that cplex finds "appropriate" remains mysterious for me... Thanks for this additional information.